# How to implement onClick in my activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-studio

I have list of passwords (strings) in a database.
In my activity i put EditText (the user will write there his/her password) and a button.
How i can implement onClick for the button that will check if the password are in the system (in the list)?
[image: in the image you can see part of the xml code]

Answer (score 0):

Define a method called onClick() in your activity - this will get called when the button is clicked (as you specified in your XML). You can then retrieve the EditText text, and check it against the passwords in your DB.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    CharSequence enteredPassword = myEditText.getText();
    // TODO check if input matches a string in the DB
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement OnClickListener to the control you want the user to click on:

```
 Button mLoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    mLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Login();
        }
    });
```

Create the listener event "Login":

```
  private void attemptLogin() {

  //check login is valid

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the button
`btn.addActionListener( this );`
and then do this
    
    `public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
    {
        if( event.getSource() == btn )
        {
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

```
    You can do like this:

     Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        loginButton .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String pwd = password.getText().toString();
                checkLogin(pwd)
            }
        })

    private void checkLogin(String password) {

     //db is your db instance.this is dummy query.You may have a user name editText as well
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE TRIM(password) = '"+password.trim()+"'", null);
    //check if cursor returns data
       if (!(c .moveToFirst()) || c .getCount() ==0){
         //cursor is empty
    }
    else
    {
`//cursor is not empty`    
     }
    }
```